# AWS ElastiCache with Spring

Tags: spring, caching, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use elasticache with my application built with Spring 3.0

Can anyone help about the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution - the configuration is same as memcached config.

1. Add the following in **pom.xml**

---

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmemcached-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

1. Add the follow in **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

---

```
<bean name="memcacheManager" class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache">
                <constructor-arg name="cache" index="0" ref="defaultCache"/>
                <!-- 3 days -->
                <constructor-arg name="expiration" index="1" value="259200"/>
                <!-- @CacheEvict(..., "allEntries" = true) doesn't work -->
                <constructor-arg name="allowClear" index="2" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </set>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean name="defaultCache" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
    <property name="cacheName" value="defaultCache"/>
    <property name="cacheClientFactory">
        <bean name="cacheClientFactory" class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl"/>
    </property>
    <property name="addressProvider">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
            <property name="address" value="xxx.yyy.cache.amazonaws.com:11211"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="consistentHashing" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

Where **namespaces** are as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd">
```